# Is using a server as bridge secure enough to protect the end data?

Tags: account-security, network-scanners, content-security-policy

It comes to my mind a security problem that I would have accessing some data. My current problem is the following:

1. There is a server in AWS London where you can access some data,
   by law, that data should be accessible only by Europe.
2. I want to access that data being in Brazil physically but operationally
   talking in Europe.
3. I want to avoid at all cost data that could be stolen or seen by a third party.

My question is this:

Is it secure that I could for example create an AWS server in Frankfurt let's say, connect it from Brazil via ssh and from there connect to London's server. Legally will be Europe, technically is possible, my question is, how secure could this be? or for example create a GCP instance and access it to the web console/shell to ssh my server and from it connect to the one in Frankfurt?

I'm very unsure what could be like a "really" secure option given these circumstances. Is there a really secure way to do it? even if I connect to a computer in Frankfurt via a remote desktop or ssh tunnel and later connect to the server I will have the same problem?

Ideas?

Comment: Is your approach secure? Probably. But will it satisfy your compliance requirements? Probably not. You're clearly trying to access the data from outside Europe.

Comment: Hi, I am actually trying to access a database

Answer (score 1):

As long as the AWS London server, *not sure how the server location is enforced*, supports a secure (HTTPS) connection, any kind of bridge that doesn't break the connection should be fine.

You can accomplish the same thing simply by using a commercial VPN and selecting a Europe based access point.

*Legally mandated location access restrictions are doomed to failure.*